# Erro no PHPMailer - Undefined class constant 'ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS'

Tags: php, phpmailer

Olá, executei o código, mas aparece o seguinte erro:

> Undefined class constant 'ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS'

Segue meu código:

```
<?php

require "./bibliotecas/PHPMailer/Exception.php";
require "./bibliotecas/PHPMailer/OAuth.php";
require "./bibliotecas/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
require "./bibliotecas/PHPMailer/POP3.php";
require "./bibliotecas/PHPMailer/SMTP.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//print_r($_POST);

class Mensagem {
    private $para = null;
    private $assunto = null;
    private $mensagem = null;

    public function __get($atributo) {
        return $this->$atributo;
    }

    public function __set($atributo, $valor) {
        $this->$atributo = $valor;
    }

    public function mensagemValida() {
        if(empty($this->para) || empty($this->assunto) || empty($this->mensagem)){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

$mensagem = new Mensagem();

$mensagem->__set('para', $_POST['para']);
$mensagem->__set('assunto', $_POST['assunto']);
$mensagem->__set('mensagem', $_POST['mensagem']);

//print_r($mensagem);

if(!$mensagem->mensagemValida()) {
    echo 'Mensagem não é válida';
    die();
} 

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp1.example.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Não foi possível enviar este e-mail!!"; 
    echo 'Detalhes do erro: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido.

Para quem tiver o mesmo problema é só trocar a criptografia ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS por tls ou ssl, dependendo do servidor.